# Code doesn't run when I had one more elsif statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods, nomethoderror, puts

Can anyone please explain to me why my code doesn't run when I have my second `elsif` statement in. I'm sure it's something simple but I've been over it a few times, wrote out the code again and still can't work out the bug. It only bugs when line 25 to 30 are in and says

> undefined method`[]' on line 35

but this error will change to something else if I run it again.

So this is affecting `line_three` as a test I am trying "Southern Cross" for the starting location and "Windsor" for the destination.

This is an error message I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
pt_planner.rb:35:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

another is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
pt_planner.rb:33:in `<main>': undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Hope this edit helps

```
require 'pry'

line_one = ["flinders street", "richmond", "east richmond", "burnley", "hawthorn", "glenferrie"]
line_two = ['Flagstaff', 'Melbourne Central', 'Parliament', 'Richmond', 'Kooyong', 'Tooronga']
line_three = ['Southern Cross', 'Richmond', 'South Yarra' ,'Prahran' 'Windsor']

#1 where would you like to go capture input
puts "what is your starting location?"
user_input_1 = gets.chomp
puts "what is your end location"
user_input_2 = gets.chomp


if line_one.include?(user_input_1) == true and 
    line_one.include?(user_input_2) == true
    origin_index = line_one.index(user_input_1)
    destination_index = line_one.index(user_input_2) 
    route = line_one
elsif  
    line_two.include?(user_input_1) == true and 
    line_two.include?(user_input_2) == true
    origin_index = line_two.index(user_input_1)
    destination_index = line_two.index(user_input_2)
    route = line_two
elsif
    line_three.include?(user_input_1) == true and
    line_three.include?(user_input_2) == true
    origin_index = line_three.index(user_input_1)
    destination_index = line_two.index(user_input_2)
    route = line_three
end

stops = destination_index - origin_index

puts "origin: #{route[origin_index]}\ndestination: #{route[destination_index]}\n#{route.slice(origin_index +1, stops)}\n stops total: #{destination_index - origin_index}"

binding.pry
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show exactly the code where the error occurred not some edited or "working" version). Also, please add the full error message and the full stack trace. Finally, please add which input data you use to reproduce the error.

Comment: I've made ammendments hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to search in wrong array

Change

```
destination_index = line_two.index(user_input_2)
```

to

```
destination_index = line_three.index(user_input_2)
```

Also you don't need to compare with `true`. `include?` returns `true` or `false`, that's enough. It's better to use `&&` instead of `and`. And put condition on one line with `elsif`

You can refactor like this to check both values are in the array

```
([user_input_1, user_input_2] - line_three).empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `line_three` Array, you have forgotten the comma between `'Prahran'` and `'Windsor'`. As such, Ruby parses this as a string continuation and adds a single element as `'PrahranWindsor'` here.

With that, none of your `if` or `elsif` conditions match. Consequently, note of the variables you set on any of the branches will be set and instead will be implicitly initialized as `nil`. As you assume these variables to be set later in your program, things break.

To fix this, you should at first fix the definition of your `line_three` array.

You should also add code to handle the case that none of your queries matched. Here, you could add a final `else` branch which e.g. shows an error message and asks the user to try again.

Comment: Thank you!
I won't be adding an else statement yet. I still need to write code for routes that have connecting lines.